# how to add gradient to image and text in frame layout

Tags: android, image

I have this layout and i want to add gradient to be like this:

[image]

This is my layout:

```
<FrameLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">


<ImageView
    android:layout_width="390dp"
    android:layout_height="207dp"
    android:id="@+id/appImage"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top"
    android:src="@drawable/download1" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:text="Medium Text"
    android:id="@+id/appName"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this as your ParentLayout background (Create a xml file in drawable):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
<gradient android:angle="270"
    android:endColor="@color/black" />
</shape>
```

Add background here:

```
<FrameLayout 
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/name_given_to_xml_file"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">


<ImageView
    android:layout_width="390dp"
    android:layout_height="207dp"
    android:id="@+id/appImage"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top"
    android:src="@drawable/download1" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:text="Medium Text"
    android:id="@+id/appName"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom" />
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: its no yellow , this is snap chat logo , so its white

Answer (score 0):

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/appImage"
    android:layout_width="390dp"
    android:layout_height="207dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top"
    android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/appName"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
    android:text="Medium Text"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

And gradient_drawable.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:shape="rectangle">
<gradient
    android:angle="90"
    android:startColor="#636348"
    android:endColor="#FFFF00"
/>
</shape>
```

Comment: its now yahoo , its snap chat logo

Answer (score 0):

[image: I got this exactly from following]

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/appImage"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top"
    android:background="@drawable/snapchat"/>


<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/gradient_drawable"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"></RelativeLayout>
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/appName"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
    android:text="SnapChat"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

And drawable should be

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:shape="rectangle">
<gradient
    android:angle="90"
    android:startColor="@android:color/black"
    android:endColor="@android:color/transparent"
/>
</shape>
```